# Text (letters) to number in C

Tags: c, encryption

i'm trying to create an RSA algorithm for study purposes.

Lets say i took an input from the user; "aer". The integer value of this char array would be 97, 101, 114 in ASCII format. I want to be able to group these chars in a way like "97101114" and use them in a computation for encryption to something else, then decrypt again into the same number and same char array eventually.

I can encrypt them by using atoi, strtol, etc. But i don't know how to decrypt again by splitting them into their old values.

Edit: While searching through the web i came an across a idea where they map each character to some kind of number as globally. Similar to ASCII mapping. But that gave me the idea to map every character to "three digit" number, so i can split them by this criteria after decryption of the whole decimal number. Is there a better solution you can provide?

Comment: You will need to provide more details to get help. For eg You may want to add an example

Comment: Lets say i took an input from the user; "aer". The integer value of this char array would be 97, 101, 114 in ASCII format. I want to be able to group these chars in a way like "97101114" and use them in a computation for encryption to something else, then decrypt again into the same number and same char array eventually. I can encrypt them by using atoi, strtol, etc. But i don't know how to decrypt again by splitting them into their old values.

Comment: Add this as part of your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a basic algorithm in your grouped ASCII numbers. 
As you said:

*"a" is going to be "97"*

*"e" is going to be "101"*

*"r" is going to be "114"*

Since you already know the ASCII provisions of your chars, you can find out how many digits of this char's ASCII provisioned number, and use it as your guidance while you are solving the equation. Let me give you an example:

97 is 2 digits

101 is 3 digits

114 is 3 digits

So your new cipher will be: **2**97**3**101**3**114

When you read this number's first element, you are going to understand that you need to read next two numbers and turn it into a character. Then when you read next number as "3", you are going to understand that next three elements are going to be handled together, etc.

Comment: Shouldn't OP use fixed-width hexadecimal instead? I think this only further overcomplicates the solution.

Comment: At least it is an option to take, I didn't say it is the "best" way, I just provided an option. @Rhymoid

Comment: you can find lots of questions and automatically answers in the websites like codechef etc.